# Alternative to position: relative; for overflow: auto; bug in IE7

Tags: css, scriptaculous, internet-explorer-7

I have content arranged thusly:

```
<div id="thumbnails" style="width: 40px; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 20px;">content</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 20px;">content</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 20px;">content</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 20px;">content</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 20px;">content</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 20px;">content</div>
```

In IE7 this shows up with the content running out of the scrollable box. The answer everywhere is to make #thumbnails position:relative. My problem is that the items in #thumbnails are scriptaculous draggables that drag outside of thumbnails with a ghost of the element that is positioned absolutely. This does not go over well if the parent is positioned:relatively because now the absolute positions are relative to #thumbnails and not the `<body>`. Does anyone know an alternative solution to the IE7 bug?

Comment: Perhaps if you were to give a full example that shows the problem clearly? (your example looked fine to me in IE7)

Comment: I was assuming familiarity with the bug, the code was merely for reference to my problem. An example of the bug is here http://www.rowanw.com/bugs/overflow_relative.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about this annoying IE "hasLayout" property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481(VS.85).aspx (quoting some msdn hurts, I feel dirty now...). Anyway, try to apply "zoom: 1" to you container: it might improve the situation. Only issue: zoom property is IE only and will create a warning in your css logs under another browser.

Comment: Yeah, I did find that. It wasn't a hasLayout problem. I ended up creating a new event in scriptaculous that fires before initializing a draggable. I handle that event, position "thumbnails" relative and set visibility: hidden to all of "thumbnails" children. Then onDragEnd, set everything back to visible and relative.  Thanks for the suggestion though.